# How to set the playback speed in MPV through the command line

Tags: mpv

How would you set the playback speed to a specific value in MPV using the builtin command line of MPV?

EDIT: I'm not talking about the --speed argument when launching the program through the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

On [the manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/) it is documented as `mpv --speed=1.2`
ex: change 1.2 to 1.4

Sorry just saw the edit...